# How can we have a same layout for all the WPF forms?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I tried to create a layout using window layout and use it for all the windows forms. But could not link user-control with the windows forms.Its like having the top and bottom of the page to be repeated for all the win forms that i have in a solution in visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

There is an example of master page pattern implementation for WPF.

This pattern consists on having a shared structure (like header, body and footer) that the contents can be overwritten in other pages. In this case, in other windows.

You can find the complete solution on https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/678020/Master-page-in-WPF

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please summarize the answer that can be found in the linked article, so your answer doesn't succumb to link-rot.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I edited the answer. Is it better?

Comment: You may want to give a more extensive summary of how to implement the master page pattern.